# How to implement flexbox within parent div element?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I want to make my page fit to screen height, and have scrollable content inside of it, but I have encountered a problem where I can't exactly  do it due to the framework I'm using (Nuxt & Buefy) generates element that I can't control.

This is how I want the page to look like

[image: My desired design]

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0
    }
    .navbar {
      height: 65px;
      background: #dd7777
    }
    .box {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .box .row {
      border: 1px dotted grey;
    }

    .box .row.header {
      flex: 0 1 auto;
    }

    .box .row.content {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .box .row.footer {
      flex: 0 1 40px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="auto-generated-top-elemennt">
      <div class="navbar">
      Something
      </div>
      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="row header">
            <p><b>header</b>
              <br />
              <br />(sized to content)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="row content">
            <p>
              <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="row footer">
            <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How I want it to look like is [similar to this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space#comment64137087_24979148) but somehow it doesn't work well..

Comment: your height:100% aren't following, you need to cascade them from the html until the box (without missing any element)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't understand what you mean by that, or how to do that. I've tried to manually change the height of every single elements involved, but there's no visible result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need more flexboxes

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0
}
.auto-generated-top-elemennt {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100%;
}
.main-content,
.box{
  flex:1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height:0;
}
.navbar {
  height: 65px;
  background: #dd7777
} 
.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="auto-generated-top-elemennt">
  <div class="navbar">
    Something
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="row header">
        <p><b>header</b>
          <br />
          <br />(sized to content)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row content">
        <p>
          <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>content</b> (fills remaining space)
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row footer">
        <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does that means for every single autogenerated elements nuxt create, just for me to flex that component, I need to add that style?

Comment: @ZombieChibiXD yes, you need to cascade your style .. the first one need to have 100% to get the 100% of the body then you need to use flexbox for all the nested container